# CloneNotSupportedException not thrown on calling clone() method on object that does not implement Cloneable interface

Tags: java

I recently started Java programming and according to Java SE API Documentation, the **Cloneable** interface is implemented to indicate that clone operations on that class are allowed. If not, then a **CloneNotSupportedException** is thrown. However in a practice session i managed to run a program that cloned a class that does not implement the Cloneable interface and no exception was thrown. I need to know why the exception was not thrown. I am using JDK 6 update 45 and latest Eclipse IDE on Windows 7. The following is the code:

```
package com.warren.project.first;

public class PracticeClass {

   //explicit initialisation of PracticeClass Instance Variables
   private int fieldOne=1;
   private int fieldTwo=2;
   private int fieldThree=3;

   //setters and getters for instance fields of PracticeClass
   public void setField1(int field1){
     this.fieldOne=field1;
   }

   public void setField2(int field2){
     this.fieldTwo=field2;
   }

   public void setField3(int field3){
     this.fieldThree=field3;
   }

   public int getField1(){
     return this.fieldOne;
   }

   public int getField2(){
     return this.fieldTwo;
   }

   public int getField3(){
     return this.fieldThree;
   }


   //This method clones the PracticeClass's instances and returns the clone
   @Override
   public PracticeClass clone(){
      PracticeClass practiceClass= this;
      return practiceClass;
   }

}


package com.warren.project.first;

public class AppMain {

  public static void main(String[] args) {      
    //Create PracticeClass Object
    PracticeClass pc1=new PracticeClass();

    //Set its instance fields using setters
    pc1.setField1(111);
    pc1.setField2(222);
    pc1.setField3(333);

    //Display Values to screen
    System.out.println(pc1.getField1()+" "+pc1.getField2()+" "+pc1.getField3());

    //Create clone of PracticeClass object
    PracticeClass pc2=pc1.clone();

    //Print values from PracticeClass clone object
    System.out.println(pc2.getField1()+" "+pc2.getField2()+" "+pc2.getField3());
  }

}
```

This code executes successfully without any exception thrown. Why isn't the **CloneNotSupportedException** thrown?

Comment: Not sure what you're going on about. You created a method called `clone()` in your class, and you called it. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: This method is not cloning, `pc1` and `pc2` are the same object.

Comment: @Dahaka that's not the issue, the issue is why the method doesn't throw the expected exception as specified in the Object contract

Comment: @morgano I know, but there is no need for `clone()` if it just does the same as `pc2 = pc1`

Comment: He/She doesn't really want to clone the object but verify that invoking clone() on a class overriding clone() will throw CloneNotSupportedException if it doesn't implement Cloneable

Answer (score 6):

In order for `CloneNotSupportedException` to be thrown, you must call `super.clone()` inside your own `clone()` method. This method will verify if your class implements `Cloneable`

Comment: Agree, but why do we need to add super.clone()? We are overriding a method and that don't need super.<supermethod>() to be call. Its optional.